# Backbone.js: stage new model without saving

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

Is there a way in backbone.js to set up a new model (i.e. instantiate the class with empty attributes), *without* saving it back to the server?

Specifically, I have a collection which contains several items.  When I want to create a new item within my collection, I call `collection.create {}`.  This automatically saves the empty model back to my database.

In Rails, there's a difference between `Class.create`, which actually creates a database record, and `Class.new`, which simply creates one in memory and has to be manually saved.  I'm basically looking for a backbone equivalent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of Collection.create, use [Collection.add](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-add).